# How do I make the background of a sprite transparent on Android?

Tags: android, transparency, sprite, game-development

I'm developing a game for Android. For the purpose of this question let's assume that I have a sprite of a red ball moving in space over some background or whatever.

I have a PNG file which I use to draw my background and a PNG file which I use to draw my ball over the background. The problem is my ball is a red circle on a 20 X 20 pixels PNG, meaning I have some white 'left over', so when I draw it on the screen, the 'white left over' appears over my background when I only want the red circle to.

I'm sorry but I'm totally new to animation. How do I crop my circle out of my square PNG or otherwise make the background in my ball PNG transparent? Do I do it programmatically or is there a way to paint my PNG so the non-relevant part is transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programs like Photoshop and GIMP allow you to set the background as transparent instead of white. Try editing your PNG in one of these and removing the white.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Paint.NET](http://getpaint.net). You can use the magic wand to select the area you want to make transparent and then press "cut" (the scissor symbol) or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.